# How to fix: Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, warnings

I keep getting this error on the script below and am not sure how to fix the problem.  I've searched and read tons of articles but just not getting it.  What am I missing?  Any help is sincerely appreciated!!

"Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/37/8642937/html/settingupsearch.php on line 42"

```
<?php

$var = @$_GET['q'] ; // get the query for the search engine (if applicable)
$trimmed = trim($var); //trim whitespace from the stored variable

{
        $con = mysql_connect("***","***","***");
        if (!$con)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }
}

$field = "title";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Listings WHERE ($field) LIKE'%$trimmed%' ORDER BY id"); 

$result = mysql_query($query); 

?>

<form name="search" method="GET" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
Search the database for: <input type="text" name="q" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>

<?
if ($trimmed == "")
{
echo "<p>Please enter a search...</p>";
exit;
}

// check for a search parameter
if (!isset($var))
{
echo "<p>We dont seem to have a search parameter!</p>";
exit;
}

$numresults=mysql_query($query);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($numresults);

if ($numrows == 0)
{
echo "<h4>Results</h4>";
echo "<p>Sorry, your search: &quot" . $trimmed . "&quot returned zero results</p>";
}

// next determine if s has been passed to script, if not use 0
if (empty($s))
{
$s=0;
}

// get results
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query");

if($numrows > 1){ $return = "results";}
else{ $return = "result"; }

// display what the person searched for
echo "<p>Your search for &quot" . $var . "&quot returned $numrows $return.</p>";

// begin to show results set
$count = 1 + $s ;

while ($r= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $r["ID"];
$title = $r["title"];
$date = $r["price"];
$city = $r["city"];

$count++ ;

?>

<a href="http://www.***.com/archive/<? echo $title ?>/<? echo $id ?>.html"><? echo $price ?></a>

<? echo $city ?>


<? } ?>
```

Comment: @MikeB - I'm new.  Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

In looking at your code it appears you have an error in it:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Listings WHERE ($field) LIKE'%$trimmed%' ORDER BY id");
```

This is wrapped in a mysql_query, then you call it again with mysql_query.